# Automate FBX Import and Retargeting

Tags: automation, ui-automation, unreal-engine5

I have 100's of FBX animations that need to be imported and retargeted onto a Metahuman body and face. I'm using some templated assets from Reallusion (iClone) to make the retargeting really simple. In fact it's done in one or two clicks.

What I'm trying to do is to automate all this, either with a Python script or some other means.

My question is to ask what of the following could be automated and what cannot:

1. Import the FBX and change some of the default import settings, like unchecking the "Import Skeletal Mesh" checkbox and choosing an existing asset as my target mesh
2. Delete any other assets that get imported (when I import the FBX file it splits into two Animation Sequences - an A-Pose sequence and the actual animation sequence. I can delete the A-Pose sequence)
3. Rename the animation sequence asset using a very structure naming convention
4. Open the resulting Animation Sequence for Body animation FBX and choose a Retarget Source Asset (it will always be the same asset for every import) and then save that sequence
5. Open the resulting Animation Sequence for Face animation FBX and choose a Preview Pose Asset (it will always be the same asset for every import) and save that sequence
6. Create a new cinematic Level Sequence, create a Metahuman animation track, delete the control rigs and apply the Body animation to the Body track and the Face animation to the Face track
7. Add an audio track and apply the corresponding audio asset to that track and then save the Sequence.

I have to do the above steps 100's of times and while I can batch import, all these other little steps will be death by 1000 cuts... What of the above could be automated and what's the best scripting environment to do it in?

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to tell you exactly what you can automate. But with Unreal Engine's Python API and the Editor Scripting Utilities plugin you can automate a lot of those steps. You could create an Editor Utility Widget to give you an interface to handle imports and change assets. Here is the API as of this writing: [UE 5.3 Unreal Python API](https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.3/en-US/PythonAPI/). The API includes functions for managing assets, asset editing tasks, working with animations, sequences and sound.

Here is the documentation page about using [Unreal Engine's Python API.](https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.3/en-US/scripting-the-unreal-editor-using-python/)
Since you intend to work with assets, be aware of the following when using Python:

> If you need to work with Assets in your Project, always use functions from the Unreal Python API to do it. Never use file management modules built in to Python to work directly with your Asset files on disk. For example, if you need to move an Asset to a different folder, do not use Python functions like os.rename or shutil.move. Unreal Projects and Assets contain internal content references that you can break if you do not respect this rule.
>
> Instead, we recommend using the unreal.EditorAssetLibrary API that is
> provided by the Editor Scripting Utilities plugin, or the
> unreal.AssetTools class built in to the Unreal Python API.

Comment: Thanks for this, and for the reminder about avoiding system-level file operations. I got frustrated with the API because the documentation was so sparse - you really have to KNOW what classes to use in order to find the relevant properties or methods on those classes that do what you want. 

Beyond the documentation links you provided (I'm locked to 5.1 for this project right now), are there any guides or "recipes" that can help developers discover or understand what API methods they should look at in order to accomplish the automation tasks I've listed out?